# Student Pilot Spreadsheet - Retrieving date of last landing

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google

**Overview**

As a student pilot I try to keep record of all my flights, total hours, costs and number of landings in Google Sheets.
As a safety measure our aviation safety agency (EASA) requires pilots to perform a minimum of 3 take-offs and landings within 90 days in order for them to take passengers on a flight.

**Question**

Even though I fly very regularly, I would still like to know exactly how many days I have left since the last time I've performed 3 take-off's and landings.

In my spreadsheet I have a column for the date of each flight and a column which sums up the amount of landings that were made (as shown in the extract below).

**Aim**

My goal is to count column D from the bottom to top until the value sums up **3** and read back the related date on the same row (in red).

**What have I done so far?**

I have been experimenting with COUNTIF, ARRAY, INDEX, SUMIF and a combination of them but I'm out of clues. That is why I am reaching out to you.

The best I came up with (Q42 is a cell with value '3' in it). Unfortunately it leaves much to be desired:

```
=COUNTIF(ArrayFormula (SUMIF (ROW(D2:D19); "<=" &ROW(D2:D19); A2:A19)); "<=" &Q42)
```

[image: Screenshot Sheets]

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

Use `sumif()` and `query()`, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 
      A2:A19, 
      sumif( row(D2:D19), ">=" & row(D2:D19), D2:D19 ) 
    }, 
    "select Col1 where Col2 >= " & Q42 &  
    "order by Col1 desc limit 1", 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

If your **File > Settings > Locale** is such that the spreadsheet uses commas as decimal separators, you will have to use semicolons and backslashes, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  query( 
    { 
      A2:A19
      \ 
      sumif( row(D2:D19); ">=" & row(D2:D19); D2:D19 ) 
    }; 
    "select Col1 where Col2 >= " & Q42 &  
    "order by Col1 desc limit 1"; 
    0 
  ) 
)
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! 
I tried implementing your formula into my sheet, but unfortunately ran into an error: "QUERY PARSE ERROR ENCOUNTERED "<ID> Col2"" at line 1, column 19. Was expecting one of: "("... "("...

Not sure what it is expecting though. The brackets look fine.

Comment: Make sure cell `Q42` contains a value like `3`. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data.

Comment: Thanks again. I should have shared the sheet earlier. Nevertheless, here is a link: [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p_VtQ_3_o9Tdqaq0YYOVSK3DR5uYMCzWj2uNk2Yc3Mk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Edited the answer to add a formula localized for Netherlands. See your [sample spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p_VtQ_3_o9Tdqaq0YYOVSK3DR5uYMCzWj2uNk2Yc3Mk/edit#gid=0).